# My WAMP server doesn't show the edited file

Tags: html, wampserver

My `WAMP` server doesn't show the edited file but still shows the old one that doesn't exist anymore. When I open the html file without WAMP it shows the edited file. 
I've made sure I opened the correct file using the correct path but still nothing happens. Also when I change the directory, like a new folder name, and open it in WAMP it does show the changes.

Comment: Probably browser has cache. Clear cache & reload

Comment: check the exact page and try in private window of browser

Comment: @VikasGautam looks like it works in a private browser

Comment: @Raptor I've tried to clear the cache and reload but that didn't work

Comment: How did you clear the cache, (CTRL+F5) should clear the cache. You should not need to use a private window

Comment: if its working in priivate window it mean its working fine

Comment: @VikasGautam It's still not working in a normal browser also I've tried CTRL+F5 and it doesn't do anything

Comment: Everything worked perfectly a week ago until yesterday when it started to do this weird thing.

Comment: try ctrl+ R and  remove the browser history  from option in Mozilla and setting from chrome and remove all the cookies and cache @Pepijn

Comment: @VikasGautam I've tried that. Everything I've tried: clear cache, clear browser history, clear cookies, refresh and reinstalled wamp.